# non-split Frobenius map 

Tags: finite-fields

there are 3 simple groups arising from $SO(8)$, i.e.$ SO(8,F_{q})$, $2D_4(q,q^2)$,$3D_4(q,q^3),$
so I want to know 
For the $3D_4(q,q^3),$, what is the corresponding Frobenius?

Comment: So you must take the graph automorphism of order three. It does not matter which of the two you take. 

Comment: ... and the reason it doesn't matter is because the two choices are conjugate in $S_3$.

Comment: I knew this is classical result using Galois semi-automorphisms and 1-cohomology, furthermore, how to write down the Frobenius?